# A metric on $\mathbb N$ with no isolated points.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find an example of a metric on $\mathbb N$ with no isolated points.Is it possible to define such a metric?

Answer (score 4):

Let $(r_n)$ be an arrangement of rational numbers in a sequence. Define $d(n,m)=|r_n-r_m|$. This gives a metric on $\mathbb N$ with no isolated points.